# Different buttons having the same function

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I have this back and confirm button. The problem is that when I click the back button it confirms the form. Basically my back and confirm button are having the same function.

I tried putting the back button outside the  and it worked well. The problem is it would look like this:

[image: Confirm and Back]

**The thing is I want the back button to go first and then the confirm button next.** Like this:

[image: Back and Confirm]

I can only do that when the back button is inside the form. As I've said I'm having problems when I do that.

Here's my html:

```css
.form__confirmation,
.form__confirmation2 {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: #011f4b;
  border: 1px solid #DADDE8;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition: background-color 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  position: relative;
  left: 330px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #1293e1;
}

button:active {
  background-color: #1083c8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="form__name" style="font-family: Questrial; ">
      Leave Application Form
    </div>
    <div class="time__container">
      <div class="section">
        <div class="box">
          1
        </div><span>Date &amp; Time</span>
      </div>
      <form action="form-to-email.php" class="form__time" method="post">
        <div class="date">
          <label for="date">From</label> <input id="date" type="date" name="datefrom" required>
        </div>
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <div class="date">
          <label for="date">To</label> <input id="date" type="date" name="dateto" required>
        </div>
        <div class="timezone">
          <label for="timezone"></label>
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message__container">
      <div class="section">
        <div class="box">
          2

        </div><span>Message</span>
      </div>
      <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="contact__container">
      <div class="section">
        <div class="box">
          3

        </div><span>Contact Information</span>
      </div>
      <div class="form__contact">
        <div class="cname">
          <label for="cname">Name</label> <input name="name" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="cnum">
          <label for="cnum">Phone Number</label> <input id="cnum" type="text" name="phoneno" required>
        </div>
        <div class="email">
          <label for="cemail">Email</label> <input id="cemail" name="email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact__container">
      <div class="section">
        <div class="box">
          4

        </div><span>Send to</span>
      </div>
      <div class="form__contact">
        <div class="cname">
          <label for="cname">Manager</label> <select name="emailTo" required>
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="email@gmail.com">TestingRenzo</option>
     <option value="email@gmail.com">TestingPaul</option>
     </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="home.php">
      <div class="form__confirmation2">
        <button>Back</button>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="form__confirmation" type="submit" name="submit">
      <button>Confirm Information</button>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your html is horribly invalid. For starters, you cannot have a `<button>` inside of an anchor (`<a>`) tag, and you cannot have a `<div>` with `type="submit" name="submit"` - that's for an `<input>` or `<button>` only. Fixing your HTML would likely solve your problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this [horribly invalid] code:

```
<a href="home.php">
  <div class="form__confirmation2">
    <button>Back</button>
  </div>
</a>
<div class="form__confirmation" type="submit" name="submit">
  <button>Confirm Information</button>
</div>
```

To this [valid] version instead:

```
<div class="form__confirmation2">
  <a class="button" href="home.php">Back</a>
</div>
<div class="form__confirmation">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Confirm Information</button>
</div>
```

And add the `.button` class to your CSS:

```
button,
.button {
  ...
}
button:hover,
.button:hover {
  ...
}
button:active,
.button:active {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I just realize that indeed my code is horribly invalid lol. Thank you so much! Also one question, I am getting an underline with the back button, not sure why.

Comment: add `text-decoration: none` to your button styles, because the back button is just a normal hyperlink that _looks_ like a button.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is somewhat wrong. Try to minimize the DIV tags if you can then you will understand the problem. Also in the submit button DIV tag you have mentioned a wrong bootstrap class if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float:right` in order to change the positioning of your buttons. This will leave your DOM structure intact.

```
        <div class="form__confirmation" type="submit" name="submit" style="float:right;" >
            <button>Confirm Information</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <a href="home.php">
        <div class="form__confirmation2" style="float:right;">
            <button>Back</button>
        </div>
    </a>
```

This is the entire code Snippet.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="card">
    <div class="form__name" style="font-family: Questrial; ">
        Leave Application Form
    </div>
    <div class="time__container">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="box">
                1
            </div><span>Date &amp; Time</span>
        </div>
        <form action="form-to-email.php" class="form__time" method="post">
            <div class="date">
                <label for="date">From</label> <input id="date" type="date" name="datefrom" required>
            </div>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <div class="date">
                <label for="date">To</label> <input id="date" type="date" name="dateto" required>
            </div>
            <div class="timezone">
                <label for="timezone"></label> 
                    </select>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message__container">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="box">
                2

            </div><span>Message</span>
        </div>
        <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="contact__container">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="box">
                3

            </div><span>Contact Information</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form__contact">
            <div class="cname">
                <label for="cname">Name</label> <input name="name" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="cnum">
                <label for="cnum">Phone Number</label> <input id="cnum" type="text" name="phoneno" required>
            </div>
            <div class="email">
                <label for="cemail">Email</label> <input id="cemail" name="email" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact__container">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="box">
                4

            </div><span>Send to</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form__contact">
            <div class="cname">
                <label for="cname">Manager</label> <select name="emailTo" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="email@gmail.com">TestingRenzo</option>
                <option value="email@gmail.com">TestingPaul</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CHANGED BUTTON TAGS -->
    <div class="form__confirmation" type="submit" name="submit" style="float:right;" >
        <button>Confirm Information</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <a href="home.php">
        <div class="form__confirmation2" style="float:right;">
            <button>Back</button>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can I have the whole code snippet? I want to try this method too.

Comment: No problem. also I didn't notice till now that you used bootstrap, so you might not need a wrapper since .container is a wrapper class.